# Incrementing Char Issue (Hex)

Tags: java, char, hex

I'm currently using a char as a counter in a char[]. An example of the problem I'm having is below:

```
char counter = 0x00;

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
counter++;
}
```

This seemed to work well until I discovered that when  i = 10, counter was assigned 0x10 and not 0x0A.

How can I increment the char to contain the hex value and not the decimal value?

Any suggestions or advice would be great!

Comment: the simplest one can be conversion of char->int->hex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counter is assigned the correct value, you just need to convert it into hex form.

```
char counter = 0x00;

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    counter++;
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString((int) counter);
}
```

Running this prints out 1 - f on single lines.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: Thanks! The issue isn't viewing them it's getting the new value back to the char which I can't figure out :/. So If I get 9 I'm trying to assign the char object to 0x0A (However currently it's assiging 0x10).

Comment: If you have c = 0x09, and you add one (c += 1), you end up with 0x0A. There is no difference between the actual values in hex, decimal, or any base notation, it is just a different way to write the same number.

Comment: I think I've worded the question poorly, say I have a char '2' and can get the decimal value back by casting the char to a byte, however I would like the byte value to be 0x32 not 50 which is what I seem to be getting. I know I can format the returned value in a number of values but I can't store a string in a byte.

Comment: turns out I was just being a noob. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's no decimal or hex value, there's only an integer value. The decimal and hex are just formats. When i is 0, counter gets a value of 1, when i is 1, counter becomes 2. When i is 10, counter becomes 11. I have expressed all values here in decimal format.

Try this:

```
    int i = 7023;
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i, 16).toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: How would I format the char with hex rather than decimal? I guess incrementing the value is not an option.

Comment: @dan983 By using e.g. `Integer.toHexString` as Jonathan Luckin wrote.

Comment: @dan983 You can also use the `Integer.toString(val, radix)` method.